# How to replace fragment in androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView with Android databinding

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding

My current Android application employs databinding.

I having issues when attempting to add a fragment to a `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`.

I have managed to get the effect I was after, however it doesnt feel the correct approach.

I do not understand where I have made a mistake.

in my activity `onCreate` method I perform this code to set the required fragment

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) manageFragment()
    }
```

where `manageFragment()` function resembles this

```
private fun manageFragment() {
    val myFragment = MyFragment.instance()

    when {
        (currentFragment == null) -> supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.my_fragment_container, myFragment)
            .commit()

        (currentFragment is MyFragment) -> doNothing()

        else -> supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.my_fragment_container, myFragment)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

When I check after `manageFragment()` this method returns null in `onCreate()`

```
supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment_container)
```

However when I call the same method in `onPostCreate()`

```
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
    currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment_container)
}
```

It has my fragment set

Is this how I should be adding/re[placing fragments when using databinding?

Why doesnt my fragment get returned until `postCreate()`

Ive a feeling its because once I commit the fragment transaction to add my fragment to the `FragmentContainerView`, the layout still needs to be measured etc. so "some time" elapses before `findFragmentById()` can return my added fragment.

is there a layout listener I can add to `FragmentContainerView` to detect when my fragment is actually added and becomes visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why doesnt my fragment get returned until postCreate()

[Commit is asynchronous](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#async)

> is there a layout listener I can add to FragmentContainerView to detect when my fragment is actually added and becomes visible?

Why do you care about this?

Comment: I thought it was something like tis. I cared because I thought I had done something wrong. I didnt realise commit() wasnt immediate, a simple error on my part